# Allow accessibility screen reader to read a phone number string one-by-one as digits Angular

Tags: angular, internationalization, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers

`$localize:channel item subheader text@@text.sms:You'll get a code on ${phoneNumber},`

`phoneNumber = 123456789`

The screen reader reads the `phoneNumber` incorrectly as millions and billions.
Is there a way to enforce it is read as digits?

Answer (score -1):

You need to set your aria-label property to a string which the screen-reader will correctly vocalise. I'd recommend that you write a method to help you with this, noting that it will likely need to be extend to be able to handle things like area/country codes, brackets and dashes.

```
function phoneNumberToAriaString(phoneNumber: string){
    let outputString = ""
    const numDigits = 
    for(let index = 0; index < phoneNumber.length; index++) {
        const element = phoneNumber[index];
        outputString += element;
        outputString += " ";
    }

    return outputString
}
```

Note there are many ways to skin a cat and this is just one method of iterating over the string, you can find more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-iterate-over-characters-of-a-string-in-javascript/)

Comment: I would strongly discourage doing this. It makes for a terrible reading experience for the braille user. Instead of reading a phone number of digits, they'll read "number space number space number space...".